# I can't connect to remote WSS via browser but it works fine with wscat

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, ssl, websocket

I have a reverse proxy with nginx:

```
server {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
   server_name CENSURED;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
   access_log  /var/log/nginx/CENSURED.access.log;                                                                                                                                               
   error_log  /var/log/nginx/CENSURED.error_log;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   location / {                                                                                                                                                                                    
      proxy_buffering off;                                                                                                                                                                            
      proxy_request_buffering off;                                                                                                                                                                    
      # redirect all HTTP traffic to localhost:8080                                                                                                                                                   
      proxy_pass http://localhost:9090;                                                                                                                                                               
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;                                                                                                                                                        
      proxy_set_header Host $host;                                                                                                                                                                    
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      # WebSocket support                                                                                                                                                                             
      proxy_http_version 1.1;                                                                                                                                                                         
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;                                                                                                                                                         
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";                                                                                                                                                           
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;                                                                                                                                                               
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;                                                                                                                                                                      
      proxy_read_timeout 86400;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
   listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot                                                                                                                                                       
   listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot                                                                                                                                                            
   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/CENSURED/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot                                                                                        
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/CENSURED/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot                                                                                      
   include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot                                                                                                                           
   ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         }
```

The server side is made with node:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;

var wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 9090 });

wss.on('connection', function (connection) {
```

Client side

```
new WebSocket("ws:"+URL)
```

I get this server log, which seems to be a client side error? but I can't figure out how I should fix it

```
2022/07/04 12:09:19 [crit] 1809447#1809447: *45 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:142090BA:SSL routines:tls_early_post_process_client_hello:bad cipher) while SSL handshaking, client: CENSURED, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

Do I have to add something to the server side for socket to work with SSL? but I already tried a bunch of things and nothing seems to work and it's strange that is works without any issue with wscat

Comment: It is possible that you use SLL/TLS version (1.3?) that your client does not support. What exactly is the client? You can try adding `ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;` in your nginx.conf in servers to see if that's the case.

Comment: Try to add `default_server`: `listen 443 default_server ssl;`

Comment: @MartinZeitler Thanks a lot I wasted hours trying to fix this and all I had to do was add `default_server` :/
If you wanna post it as answer I'll flag it as answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

specifying `ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;` and `default server` solved the problem